# HTML to TXT library that mimics the output of "lynx -dump"?

Tags: java, html, android, html-parsing, lynx

The problem is really that specific.

**I need a library in java that can take HTML content and generate text in the same format that is generated by the Linux lynx program.**

---

I need to expose data provided by 3rd party servers to end users on Android. Data format is ancient, in badly formatted HTML, so much that I've tried reading it using java and it fails occasionally (unacceptable). It is also growing every month (preinstall ruled out) and I can't convince them to change to "modern" stuff (life would be great in XML etc.).

Shortest route: I wrote a class to use the W3 html2txt service online (google search it). It worked fine on the app until I got complains and noticed that the W3 service fails occasionally. It's not that big of a deal, but the black box logic expects the output to be in this "lynx like" text format.

So I would like a library to do the conversion (HTML->TXT) in "lynx style" inside the app and avoid the outages in the W3 service. And besides, the lynx output the probably the best I've seen, the most organized and neat.

**Are you guys aware of any?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year, I give up. Answer is: *no way to handle that, no library in Java.* At least for now.

I'm closing this. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: There has always been a commercial solution with Chilkat which has a HTML to space formated text. But without source and without any explaination how it works. Other then this: You are right even in 2019: There is no library (i any language).

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by lynx style so I might be completely off by submitting this (if so please excuse me).

I used some piece of code a while back to check HTML/XML files (at the time I was just priting it out in the logs

InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(id); 
StringBuffer inLine = new StringBuffer();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader inRd = new BufferedReader(isr);

String text;
while ((text = inRd.readLine()) != null) {
    inLine.append(text);
    inLine.append("\n");
}
in.close();
return inLine.toString();

I hope it helps but I got the feeling you need something more complex :P

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, I don't need to check. Actually, I need to work with defective HTML files, so checking the validity of the HTML is not really the point.

Comment: I hate pressing ENTER here on stackoverflow... anyway... since my app contacts the W3 service every time it needs to convert the data that it gets from the servers, I was wondering if I could do this work "in house", so as to not depend on the W3 service. The lynx format is just a requirement. Thank you again.